# Distributed atomic list: synchronization between microservices

Tags: concurrency, synchronization, microservices, distributed-computing

Currently, I've deployed two services: `front` and `back`:

`back` asks to `front` for pending `resources` to be digested by `back`.

1. `back` asks for pending resources ids to `front`.
2. For each received resource id:

   - `back` downloads the entire resource according to its `id`.
   - `back` digests received resource.
   - `back` sends confirmation to `front`.

It's working well, but it doesn't scale. I mean, what about if I want to scale `back` up to 2 replicas?

Then, two `back` instances are going to pull for pending `resources` regardless of whether the other one is digesting the same `resource`.

I hope I've explained so well.

Any ideas?

Comment: Why not just let front put pending resources on a queue and let each consumer (back) pull a resource on demand?

Answer (score 0):

Not quite sure if I got your context, but it sounds like what many database (+like) services offer.  Etcd, for example, is a distributed key-value store rather than traditional database.  It uses versioning of the keys ( key + count ) to track historical versions, and provides a sort of distributed transaction monitor based on the raft consensus algorithm (https://raft.github.io/).

There are many similar services to choose from with various niches.
They are considered *lightweight* in the same way unix instances are considered *microservices*.

Answer (score 0):

Some possibilities, with variations:

1. After giving out a resource for processing, "front" puts it aside for a configurable or specified in the request period of time: if acknowledgement has not been received within that time, "front" redelivers it. Classes of systems most of which do that out of the box are `message queues`, `work queues`, `task queues` (e.g. `RabbitMQ` [1](https://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-two-python.html), [2](https://www.rabbitmq.com/confirms.html); but also `ActiveMQ`, `SQS` and maybe others), the particular terms to search are e.g. `"acknowledge processing"` or `"confirm completion"`.
2. A newcomer "back" service registers with the "front", then some form of "liveness detection", e.g. periodic heartbeats, is used by the front to determine if it's still in. The front decides which "back" gets which resources (e.g. if 2 "backs": one gets "odd" ids, the other gets "even" ids).
3. Make the "back" services be aware of their configuration. For example, make the "back" services all participate in a cluster (like `Zookeeper`, `etcd`, `JGroups` (if in Java), some form of a gossip protocol). Once the second service "joins" the cluster, the first service starts asking for resources with "odd" ids, the second – with the "even" ids. When a service "dies", the other one gets aware of this and starts again asking for all ids. This approach looks like a (huge) overkill in your case to me.